# how to validate azure active directory token in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am trying to validate azure active directory token got in angularapp

i used following code in web api

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("Validate")]
    public JwtSecurityToken Validate(string token)
    {
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";


        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            IssuerSigningTokens = config.SigningTokens,
            ValidateLifetime = false
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        SecurityToken jwt;

        var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

        return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
    }
```

the code show error at `IssuerSigningTokens = config.SigningTokens`, with the message

> TokenValidationParameters does not contain definition for
>   IssuerSigningTokens

Can any one please provide me the solution?

Also i want to return my own token from validate method.

Comment: What's the kind of your app? If it's `.NET Core` App, that's should be `IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys`.

Comment: dotnet famework 4.5.2

Answer (score 3):

Today,we can use `jwtSecurityTokenHandler` with [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/).

**ATTENTION**
*System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 5.x.x requires .NET Framework 5.x.
If the target framework is .NET Framework 4.5.x or 4.6.x take latest stable 4.x.x version of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package.*

**Validate JWT**

```cs
public override async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...

    // validate JWT
    try
    {
        await JwtValidator.ValidateJwtToken(token, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (SecurityTokenException e)
    {
        var validationSucceeded = false;
        Contract.Assert(validationSucceeded, $"{ErrorCode.UNAUTHORIZED}JWT validation failed ({e.Message}).");
    }

    ...
}

public class JwtValidator
{
    private const string STS_DISCOVERY_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX = ".well-known/openid-configuration";
    private const string URI_DELIMITER = "/";

    public static async Task<SecurityToken> ValidateJwtToken(string token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        var tenant = "example.com";
        var audience = "853fb202-4201-4e20-97ae-4d5840d9490f";
        var authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        // Fetch configuration
        var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Concat(authority, URI_DELIMITER, STS_DISCOVERY_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX);
        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);
        var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken);

        // extract issuer and token for validation
        var issuer = config.Issuer;
        var signingTokens = config.SigningTokens.ToList();

        // validate token
        var validationParameters = CreateTokenValidationParameters(signingTokens, issuer, audience);

        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        SecurityToken jwt;
        jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
        return jwt;
    }

    private static TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters(List<SecurityToken> signingTokens, string issuer, string audience)
    {
        Contract.Requires(null != signingTokens);
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(issuer));

        return new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = audience,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            IssuerSigningTokens = signingTokens,
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    }
}
```

> Also i want to return my own token from validate method.

When using `OpenIdConnectConfiguration configManager.GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken);` has to be called in async context by using await (Implies that the surrounding method has to be async).

Otherwise the method call `GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken)` did never return. Even when I tried to run the asynchronous method synchronously by calling .Result or using other mechanisms to run ansynchronous methods synchronous the method didn’t return.

You can see more details about Manual JWT Validation against Azure Active Directory in [this blog](https://d-fens.ch/2017/04/13/manual-jwt-validation-against-azure-active-directory/).

Comment: i am working on dotnet framework 4.5.2,and i have latest  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt dll(5.2.2),but i am getting error OpenIdConnectConfiguration  does not contain definition for SigningTokens

Comment: i changed dll(verion 4.0.1) ,1.getting following errors ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> does not contain constructer taking one arguement,2.OpenIdConnectConfiguration does not contain definition for SigningTokens,3.cannot convert from 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' to 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters',4.TokenValidationParameters' does not contain a definition for 'IssuerSigningTokens

Comment: Are we able to use for .net core as well?